# Error Expected Loop VBScript

Tags: loops, vbscript

I have a script that opens up an excel file if the password provided is correct. If its wrong, it prompts a message. It works perfectly when I add a loop at the end. However, the problem is whenever the password is wrong the script won't stop asking for the password because of the loop. What I want is the script to quit/close if the password is wrong. I tried to remove the loop and replaced it with "wscript.quit" but it always prompts the message "expected loop". Here is the code I made.

```
password = "pass"
do
ask=inputbox ("Please enter password:","DProject")
select case ask
case password
answer=true 

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")

xl.Application.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\test1\Desktop\test.xlsx"
xl.Application.Visible = True
Set xl = Nothing
wscript.quit
end select

answer=false
x=msgbox("Password incorrect... Aborting")
loop until answer=true
```

Is it possible to put a message like that counts when aborting. like "Aborting in 3.... 2... 1".

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method instead of the `MsgBox` function.

```
password = "pass"
do
  ...
  x = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup("Password incorrect... Aborting", 3)
Loop Until answer = True Or x < 0
```

Comment: Thanks Man. However the problem is... it did not abort.... its looping until the password is correct and never stops.

Comment: If you want the loop to stop when nobody clicked a button on the popup you can check if `x` is less than zero (see updated answer).